# Use drive images in html file in google app script project

Tags: google-apps-script

How to access my google drive images from app script html file so that i can use those images in my img tags something like src= "https/googledrive/folderID/imagename.png"

I have not able to find any relevant answer.Please help!

Answer (score 0):

you cant. ok you can but only for a few more months as google has deprecated "google drive hosting" (google that if you still want to use it)

instead you can use another free google hosting like a google site. put images in a file cabinet page and make the page public. like this image: 
https://sites.google.com/a/plusfortrello.com/images/img/bubble-sprite.png which is the cabinet site plus plus the image name appended.

sites images have disadvantages like lack of caching and slow GET. you can greatly speed it up using a (paid) Google Cloud Storage bucket mentioned in this blog post of mine: http://zigmandel.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-i-crowd-translated-my-product-tour.html